# How to embed a TCL script in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, tcl

I want to know how can i use TCL script in HTML. All i know it is related to the TCL CGI but not aware of it much. I want to create a chart using javascript of my data from the database using a particular query.

Comment: Easiest way: Tcl runs server side (various ways possible, including CGI, scgi, Tcl-based webservers) and delivers data in form that client side javascript can easily render.

Answer (score 2):

You talk of CGI, which means, you want your TCL-code executed on the *server*, not [in the browser](http://tclplugin.sourceforge.net/). (Your tagging this question with "javascript" *as well* is confusing -- if you need the client's browser to execute TCL-code, then use the above link to the TCL browser plugin.)

However, if the code is to be embedded inside HTML, then the traditional CGI is not applicable. You have two options with a few more sub-options:

1. Use [Server-Side includes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes) (SSI) in your HTML -- this is generally the easiest, but also the least-efficient method. If your web-server allows them, you can get going quickly:

```
<H1>Hello, visitor from <!-- #include virtual="print-remote-IP.tcl" --></H1>
```

2. Use one of the TCL server-modules. The ones for Apache, for example, are [here](http://tcl.apache.org/). I currently use both [Rivet](http://tcl.apache.org/rivet/) and [Websh](http://tcl.apache.org/websh/) happily, although the latter is now considered abandoned.

```
<H1>Hello, visitor from <? puts $env(REMOTE_ADDR) ?></H1>
```

I wish, I could be more specific than offer you links, but your question is too vague in itself...

Comment: Thanks Mikhail for the tips. Actually i had prepared a pie chart using js. The chart was prepared from external text file data. Not basically this data has been generated from a TCL script which got saved in csv file in my local directory.
What exactly i am looking now is when i open my html file in browser, the TCL script should automatically run and the data generated from the TCL script will return a pie chart on the page.
I hope I am able to clear a bit what i am expecting to do.

Comment: I would serve the CSV file verbatim and have the JavaScript code do the charting inside the browser. This would save your server from having to do the file-parsing for millions of visitors -- burdening _their_ computers with the work instead. Maybe, the server should convert the CSV to JSON, but that conversion only needs to be done once and so can be done outside the web-server.